# notes url (notes://) sometimes does not create icon on workspace

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm maintaining an application which sends out E-Mails with a notes url link like this:

```
noteshref = "notes://" & serverName.Common & "/" & docToLink.Parentdatabase.Replicaid & "/" & viewUNID & "/" & docToLink.Universalid
```

the viewUNID is calculated thusly:

```
    Dim viewUNID As String
    Set nc = db.Createnotecollection(False)
    nc.Selectviews=True
    nc.Selectionformula={@isMember("Vtousdocuments";@explode($Title;"|"))}
    nc.Buildcollection

    If nc.Count > 0 Then
        viewID = nc.Getfirstnoteid
        Dim note As NotesDocument
        Set note = db.Getdocumentbyid(viewID)
        viewUNID=note.Universalid
        Delete note
    Else
        viewUNID="0"
    End If
    Delete nc
```

I've looked at the documentation for the NotesURL: 
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/notes-urls

I've seen demonstrations via a remote session when the database icon on the workspace is not created when opening the link. The Document gets opened, but no bananas on the 'create a Workspace icon on the database' behaviour.

I haven't been able to reproduce this on my machine, and I've also noted that, contrary to the documentation, the server 'hint' is not considered - one of the possible replicas is pulled out of thin air and recreated on the workspace.

Am I missing anything? Are there perhaps some combinations of the notesurl that do not create icons on the workspace (i.e. a naming convention for the server)? Or could it be something more obscure, like corrupted desktop.ndks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this URL format in few places and it has always worked and it opens the right server. One thing I do differently is use `/0/` instead of the view UNID `"/" & viewUNID & "/"`. This would directly open the document if its present in the db and its also faster.

But your solution also should work, if the issue is specific for few users you should delete the cache/desktop and try.